# Get the value of select option without refreshing the page

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

My problem is very simple.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
    include "../../../koneksi.php";  
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php  
        if($_POST['menu'] === "lunchmenu"){
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tb_lunch");
        } else{
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tb_dinner");
        }
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Kategori Menu</td>
            <td>
                <select name="menu" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                    <option selected="true" disabled>-- Menu Category --</option>
                    <option value="lunchmenu">Lunch Menu </option>
                    <option value="dinnermenu">Dinner Menu </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Menu Name</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <?php  
                    if($_POST['menu'] === "lunchmenu")
                        $i = 1;
                        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
                    ?>
                    <option> <?=$row[menu_name]; ?></option>
                    <?php       
                        $i++;
                        endwhile; 
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    if($_POST['menu'] === "dinnermenu")
                        $i = 1;
                        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
                    ?>
                    <option> <?=$row[menu_name]; ?></option>
                    <?php       
                        $i++;
                        endwhile; 
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The results that I want is very simple. When I choose "Lunch Menu" from --Menu Category--, it will show me the available lunch menu. I got no problem in here. My problem is: After I choose a menu (lunch or dinner), the page will refresh and it will be back just like the default value of --Menu Category--, though it shows the correct menu below.

I think the problem is at `onchange="this.form.submit();`

Do you guys has any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain two empty variables one for lunchmenu and another for dinner menu, and one for defaultmenu, change these variables to "selected" and "" based on the POST variable as below.

**$lunchmenu changes from "" to "selected" when $_POST['menu'] === "lunchmenu" 


$dinnermenu changes from "" to "selected" when $_POST['menu'] === "dinnermenu"**

```html
<?php 
        include "../../../koneksi.php";  
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <?php  
            $defaultmenu = 'selected';
            $lunchmenu = '';
            $dinnermenu = ''; 
            if($_POST['menu'] === "lunchmenu"){
    $lunchmenu = "selected"';
    $defaultmenu  = '';
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tb_lunch");
            } else{
                $dinnermenu = "selected"';
$defaultmenu  = '';
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tb_dinner");
            }
        ?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Kategori Menu</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="menu" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                        <option <?php echo $defaultmenu ;?> disabled >-- Menu Category --</option>
                        <option value="lunchmenu" <?php echo $lunchmenu;?> > Lunch Menu </option>
                        <option value="dinnermenu"  <?php echo $dinnermenu;?>  > Dinner Menu </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Menu Name</td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <?php  
                        if($_POST['menu'] === "lunchmenu")
                            $i = 1;
                            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
                        ?>
                        <option> <?=$row[menu_name]; ?></option>
                        <?php       
                            $i++;
                            endwhile; 
                        ?>
                        <?php
                        if($_POST['menu'] === "dinnermenu")
                            $i = 1;
                            while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
                        ?>
                        <option> <?=$row[menu_name]; ?></option>
                        <?php       
                            $i++;
                            endwhile; 
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
     
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#menuform").offset().top
          }, 2000);
          return false;
      });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my problem. This solve 90% of my problem. A little problem here again is that "refresh page". My form is at the bottom of the page, so after I select the "category menu" (lunch or dinner), it will refresh once and go back to the top of the page.. I found this annoying, though all the result is already correct..

Comment: Please check the edited answer. You can use page scroll, in order to go to the form section on page reload

Answer (score 0):

You  should use Ajax. It will give you the value according to change without refreshing the page.

```
    $.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'test.php', // Here is your link which will give you desired values.
success: function(data){
    alert(data);
},
error: function(){
 alert(data)
 }
});
```

Bind this in a function and call that function from onchange event of your dropdown.

Comment: Thank you for your advise.. But I am still a beginner. I don't know anything about Ajax and how to use it. My web programming skill is just 4 months and still learning about PHP, CSS, HTML, MySQL and bootstrap..